# With a GROUP BY select, can you sort by the projection's SUM?

Tags: mysql

I have a SELECT that uses GROUP BY X. It uses SUM in the projection.  Is there any way to sort on that SUM?  The group result with the highest value should be first in results table.  I suspect there is no way to sort on this SUM since as each group is completed it's output and gone; there isn't any "collection" to sort.  There is something totally different I have to do here.  Do you have any hints?

Thank you.

(beginner)

Comment: You can order by aggregates after grouping with no problems. SUM or whatever other aggregate is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I'm not sure you meant this but here is an example

assume that there is data in a table which shows payments people have made to a bank. 
But people pay different money in different times.

*id*  *payment*  *time*
 1      10      01 04 2016
 2      20      01 02 2016
 1      35      14 03 2016
 3      22      21 01 2016
 2      50      01 04 2016


Now you want to calculate who has paid max money.

SELECT person_id, MAX(payment) AS totalPayment
from payments
group by person_id
ORDER BY totalPayment DESC
```

Comment: Ahhhh..   DOH. Thank you both.  Sometimes it's just too obvious.  Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm happy it helped. Making practise is realy helpful to  rule sql queries.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, the answer is quite simple:

```
SELECT customer, SUM(amount) FROM mytable GROUP BY customer ORDER BY SUM(amount);
```